# In Qt 5, where is the header file for my form?

Tags: qt

I'm new to Qt and the book is for Qt 4.

When I create a dialog.ui or mainwindow.ui file, it places it under the Folder forms. I do not see any header files or anything like that. How can I reference my dialog.ui it in my main.cpp file?

Getting error ui uses undefined class Ui::MainWindow.

Thank you!

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Ui::MainWindow ui;
    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
    ui.setupUi(dialog);
    dialog->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

.pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-05-22T17:21:36
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled7
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

qt 5 implementation which is autogenerated:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ui::MainWindow` is a private class which is accessible by the `MainWindow` class only. You cannot use it anywhere else (e.g. `main()`).

`Ui::MainWindow` is defined in **ui_mainwindow.h**, which is auto-generated when you compile your app.

To create an GUI based on **mainwindow.ui**, simply instantiate a `MainWindow` object:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mw;
    mw.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

Notes:

1. When you create a new *Qt Widgets Application* in Qt Creator, **main.cpp** is auto-
   generated for you. You don't need to write it yourself.
2. Qt's [User Interface Compiler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/uic.html) parses **mainwindow.ui** and generates 
   **ui_mainwindow.h** in your build directory. It is automatically run when you build 
   your app in Qt Creator. You don't need to run it manually.

Comment: I was trying to use just the code from the book. In your opinion,should I look for a qt 5 book then or stick with 4?

Comment: I recommend following the official "Getting Started" guide: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html. Most of the concepts in Qt 4 books are still valid, but there are small differences which you'll need to be aware of -- see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/portingguide.html. Also, Qt Creator has improved a lot since Qt 4 days, so some code in Qt 4 books are longer than necessary (even though they should still work). I don't think any Qt 5 books have been published yet.